# how to analyse a crash in uwp windows 10

Tags: uwp, crash, crash-reports

My Uwp app crashes frequently and it says Parameter is incorrect. How to get a crash report in details like method name and line number? I have added this in the constructor.

```
AppCenter.Start("aa448191-0c0d-4072-ac0a-f1cd9831960f",typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
```